# WPF paste unicode text with newlines into multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unicode, paste

I generate textboxes like so:

```
for (byte i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    for (byte j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        Letterbox[i, j] = new TextBox();
        Letterbox[i, j].Style = style; //MaxLength=1 among other things
        ...
```

and I'd wish that pasting string like this:

```
T
Ę
Ś
T
```

would result in first 4 textboxes containing 'T', 'Ę', 'Ś' and 'T' consecutively.
How can I achieve this?

Clarification (edit):

I want to be able to paste any string in this format (letter, enter, letter, enter...) when the application is running, not hardcode it

[Here's an image explaining what I want.](https://s1.postimg.org/wje5sfvkt/boop.png)

Comment: Doesn't `Letterbox[i, j].Text = "T"`  work for you? For new line use: `"T" + "\n"`

Comment: I want to be able to paste any string in this format (letter, enter, letter, enter...) when the application is running, not hardcode it.

Comment: Add `KeyDown` event to your textbox. When `Enter` is pressed pass `\n`

Comment: I don't think it will work. The only keys pressed would be CTRL and V

Comment: When `Ctrl + V` is pressed, a string would be pasted, right? Before assigning the string to textbox, separate the string by characters and insert `\n` after every character, then append the string. Assign this to the textbox

Comment: Why add `\n`, aren't they already there? Also - I'm not sure if I understand what you propose; it would seem to me that the text would still be only in one textbox.

Comment: Sorry now I got the point, you want to add `Letterbox[0,0].Text = "T"` ,  `Letterbox[0,1].Text = "Ę"` ,  `Letterbox[1,0].Text = "Ś"` ,  `Letterbox[1,1].Text = "T"` . Is that so? If I'm wrong, won't bother you again :/

Comment: [0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3] in this example, but yeah, something like that.

Comment: @Nobody I made a picture explaining what I want https://s1.postimg.org/wje5sfvkt/boop.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AddPasteHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobject.addpastinghandler(v=vs.110).aspx)

like so:

```
DataObject.AddPastingHandler(tb, OnPaste);
```

`OnPaste` method implementation:

```
    private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        var isText = e.SourceDataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText, true);
        if (!isText) return;

        var text = e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText) as string;
        HandlePaste(text);

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void HandlePaste(string text)
    {
        var letters = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (letters.Length == 4)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Letterbox[0, i].Text = letters[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

tb is some other `TextBox` on my window, you can use whatever suits your requirements. 
In `HandlePaste` pasted string is split by newlines and when it fits into 4 textboxes Text of each of them is set to appropriate letter. You could add some more validation here like checking if each of strings is exactly one char in length.